# When developing an R package, do I have to recompile the package every time I make a change?

Tags: function, r, package

I am developing a package in R

When I am debugging a particular function or set of functions, what is the best way to test the function?

Do I have to either use source('function.R') or R CMD build each time I want to check my changes?

(extra credit for associated emacs ess key-bindings)

Comment: Extra credit for emacs+ess... too bad Dirk just left for the train.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See also http://github.com/hadley/devtools/ which provides some tools to make this task easier.

for example, after making changes to source code, you build, install, and reload a package with the function `install()`:

```
library(devtools)
install("package_name")
```

devtools also makes it easier to:

- Reload complete package:

  ```
  load_all("pkg")
  ```
- Create or update documentation using roxygen2

  ```
  document("pkg")
  ```
- run all scripts in `/inst/test/`:

  ```
  test("pkg")
  ```
- build and R CMD check:

  ```
  check("pkg")
  ```

Comment: Now that I am gettin familiar, I see that devtools makes life is much easier, and development more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `?insertSource`, which is a new function in R 2.12.0, plus the other functions in the See Also section of that help page. Also, check out `?assignInNamespace` if your package has a Namespace.

The above presumes you are talking about updating and debugging R sources, not compiled code.

I generally have used the `source()` route to load new versions of functions I am improving/debugging, alongside the usual R debugging tools. But I haven't got Namespaces in my packages as yet. My fingers have gotten quite used to the `C-c C-l` keybinding in emacs+ess for sourcing a buffer over the years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: C-c C-l is helpful, but just to note for others, when using this on a server (in ess-remote mode), the file path starts with ~/pkg/R/fn.R rather than /server:pkg/R/fn.R 
even though when I write the file, it is to the /server:.. location
if I dont use the server location, I get the error: cannot open file '/ssh:server/home/usr/pkg/R/function.R'  have you noticed this?

Comment: @David: sorry, my emacs+ess fu is weak. I've never used it in the manner you are describing. (I presume you aren't editing the local version and expecting ESS to somehow know where the file is on the server?) Suggest you ask the above as a new question here, where it will get more eyes than a Q about R package development.

Comment: this was a great answer but now that I am getting the hang of devtools, I would say it is the best solution to the problem so I have updated and selected [Hadley's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4061424/199217).

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at the 'mvbutils' package. I use it to live-edit my packages all the time; I can add, remove, and edit functions and documentation while the package is loaded, and the changes are reflected both in the loaded version, in the installed version (so they're kept in the next R session), and [when I tell it] in the "source package". I only re-build via R CMD when I want to distribute a zipped version to someone else. To test code, I use the 'debug' package, which works fine on a loaded package.

I even use 'mvbutils' to live-edit 'mvbutils', which can be a bit hairy sometimes.

The 'mvbutils' documentation could really do with a full demo of this in action, but in theory the existing doco should show you how to proceed.

Can't help you with Emacs, sorry...

Comment: This is an excellent package, thanks. I was recently very happy to find `foodweb`, which was a great assistance in finding dependencies in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I had got the same issue and I solved it while using RStudio.

In the editor, I check the option "Source on save" for my R file that contains function. As I'm used to save my file each time I edit it (a good habit I think), the corresponding functions loaded in my R workspace is always up to date.