# Automatically "sourcing" function on change

Tags: r

While I am writing .R functions I constantly need to manually write source("funcname.r") to get the changes reflected in the workspace. I am sure it must be possible to do this automatically. So what I would like would be just to make changes in my function, save the function and be able to use the new function in R workspace without manually "sourcing" this function. How can I do that?

UPDATE: I know about selecting appropriate lines of code and pressing CTRL+R in R Editor (RGui) or using Notepad++ and executing the lines into R. But this approach has a disadvantage of making my workspace console "muddled". I would like to stop this practice if at all possible.

Comment: You might consider using an IDE, such as Emacs with ESS, or writing this line in your script file and using CTRL-R to send to the console in the base Rgui.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?  Can you tell us what platform and program you are using to write and evaluate your scripts?

Comment: I updated my initial question, please take a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4055614/199217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are prepared to package your functions into a package, you may enjoy exploring Hadley's devtools package.  This provides a suite of tools to write, test and document 
packages.

https://github.com/hadley/devtools

This approach offer many advantages, but mainly reloading the package with a minimum of retyping.

You will still have to type load_all("yourpackage") but I find this small amount of typing is small beer compared to the advantages of devtools.

For additional information, including how to setup devtools, have a look at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/development

Answer (score 4):

You can use [R studio](http://rstudio.org/) which has a source on save option.

Comment: I upvoted this reply as this is the method I am currently using.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Eclipse + StatET, you can press CTRL+R+S, which saves your script and sources it. As close to automatic as I can get.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not possible (automatically detecting disc changes without intervention or running at least one line).

R needs to read into memory functions, so a change on the disc wouldn't be reflected in the workspace without reloading your functions.

If you are into developing R functions, some amount of messiness during your development process will be likely inevitable, but perhaps I could suggest that you try writing an R-package to house your functions?

This has the advantage of being able to robustly document your functions, using lazy loading so that you have access to your functions/datasets immediately without sourcing them.

Don't be afraid of making a package, it's easy with package.skeleton() and doesn't have to go on CRAN but could be for your own personal use without distribution!  Just have fun!

Try to accept some messiness during development knowing you are working towards your goal and fighting the good fight of code organization and documentation!

We are only imperfect people, in an imperfect world, but we mean well!

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your text editor to run a system command after it saves the file, then you could use something like AutoIt (on Windows) or a batch script (on UNIX-derivative) to pass a call to source off to all running copies of R.  But that's a heck of a lot of work for not much gain.

Still, I think it's much more likely to work being event-driven on the text editor end vs. having R constantly scan for updates (or somehow interface with the OS's update-event-messaging-system).